# TLS Https error after upgrading Spring boot 2.3.2 to 2.5.12

Tags: spring-boot, spring-resttemplate

We are getting this error after upgrading Spring boot 2.3.2 to 2.5.12 - while accessing Https rest endpoint
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 : "Bad RequestThis combination of host and port requires TLS."

I have doubt, RestTemplate converting the url to Http

Pls provide your guidance or any expereince

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue too and tried downgrading the mssql-jdbc dependency from

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

It works fine but still looking for better solution without degrading the version.